# Cannot install jacquestvanzuydam/laravel-firebird via composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php, firebird

I'm running Laravel 5.5.
While trying to install [`jacquestvanzuydam/laravel-firebird`](https://github.com/jacquestvanzuydam/laravel-firebird) via Composer, 
but it fails. The Composer shows me:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>     Could not find a version of package jacquestvanzuydam/laravel-firebird matching your minimum-stability (stable). Require it with an explicit version constraint allowing its desired stability.

Comment: Maybe it is not supporting framework of `version > 5.5`?

Comment: You might get a quicker response by creating an issue on their GitHub: https://github.com/jacquestvanzuydam/laravel-firebird/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This package does not have any stable release. You need to specify branch in constrait directly:

```
composer require jacquestvanzuydam/laravel-firebird:dev-master
```

This will install version from `master` branch. List of available branches you can find or right column on https://packagist.org/packages/jacquestvanzuydam/laravel-firebird.

You may also report this issue (no stable release of this package) to package maintainer. Using branch instead of regular constraint may give unexpected compatibility breaks, you should really avoid it where possible.

Comment: It dosent work with the dev-master but with :                                                                                                                composer require jacquestvanzuydam/laravel-firebird:dev-5.5-support
However, Thanks for the help; i sign it as resolved

Answer (score 0):

Adding "minimum-stability": "dev" to composer.json before installation worked for me.